# How to use Find_IN_SET in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

```
public function job_fetch($key)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('job');
        $where = "FIND_IN_SET(".$key.", job_title) and FIND_IN_SET(".$key.", city)";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
```

In this code, I am passing a variable i.e. `$key` where `$key`is an array and it look like `Array ( [0] => java [1] => developer [2] => hibernate [3] => struts [4] => in [5] => mumbai [6] => noida [7] => delhi` and I want to fetch data by `job_title` and `city` if value lies in `$key` so how can I fix it? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: what error are you facing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function job_fetch($key)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('job');
        $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET(".$key.", job_title)");
        $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET(".$key.", city)");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do `WHERE something AND something` in codeigniter:

```
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET(".$key.", job_title)");
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET(".$key.", city)");
```